# iOS even number button press

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs

I'm developing an cross-browser app using javascript/HTML/CSS for the UI. I noticed some very weird behavior on one of my devices (iPad Pro, iOS 9.2.1).

When pressing a button an even number of times, it doesn't seem to register the button press. This is happening for all of my buttons.

I can post some of the code if it's relevant, but it's happening on all of my buttons. The code uses angular and bootstrap.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - why would you tap a button twice? What do the buttons do, are they links, do they call a JavaScript function...?

Comment: the buttons do all sorts of different things. I put a breakpoint in the code, and verified the function supposed to be called does get called with an odd number of presses, but not even. I don't know why the user might do this, and I don't know that it would prevent them from just pressing a single time right afterwards...

Comment: But doesn't the first press fire immediately, regardless of how many presses you do after? What type element is it, a `<button>`?

Comment: On iOS 10 it does. On iOS 9, it does not (I would have expected it to). That's why I asked the question - I have no idea why it's behaving this way.

Comment: Also, the button does depress both times

Comment: Can you build a minimal test case for this in a jsfiddle? (Or using Stack Overflow's on-board tools, although I'm embarrassed to admit I don't know how they work...)

Comment: Also, this only happens when pressing on the same location. The button is big enough to where I can press the button twice about an inch apart. When I do this, the button does what I expect it to. The leads me to believe that it is considering the 2 taps as a double click event?

Comment: `The leads me to believe that it is considering the 2 taps as a double click event?` that makes a lot of sense - but I don't seem to be seeing that on my iPadPro 9.7" running iOS 9.something. Let me check with a real `<button>`...

Comment: I can't get it to happen in my in-browser view - it works normally

Comment: So this is inside a HTML view inside an Angular app? (Sorry, I don't really know how any of this stuff works, I only saw this question because I'm subscribed to the `ios` tag :) Then maybe it's an Angular specific thing? It seems to have support for double click/tap events, maybe try adding that just to see if anything changes?

Comment: Your problem seems similar to that one : http://stackoverflow.com/q/25731106/644669  . Do  you have some hovering on your button ?

Comment: Zakaria, it seems like that's a similar issue, but not the same. I don't hover on my button...

Comment: It might be an Angular issue, but I'm guessing it's an iOS issue because it doesn't happen on iOS10, but does on iOS9