# Iframe youtube playbutton not triggering to play video on Touch Devices

Tags: youtube

Hello Guys (and girls) I am embedding an IFRAME of a youtube video on a website and it works perfectly on a DESKTOP VERSION.

However, when viewing it with any touch device, the play button DOESN'T trigger playing the video. The strange thing is that when you click outside the play button (on the video) it does play the video. This only occurs on touch devices and I verified and the issue is occurring across all touch devices.

This isn't a site specific issue, so you can try out embedding any Youtube video e.g:

You'll notice it plays when touching everywhere on the video EXCEPT when clicking play. If you have youtube embedded videos you'll probably having this issue as well.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have the same issue, did not yet find a solution or a workaround ...

Comment: You can try this if you missed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135086/the-play-button-on-a-youtube-embed-does-not-work-on-android-chrome

Comment: Indeed there is a temp fix &ps=docs, however this hides the availability to go Full screen even though controls=1

Comment: That is correct - unfortunately. If you figure this one out completely please let me know

Comment: They have fixed it. It seems to be working now :)
BTW now difficulties with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972600/ios-8-embedded-youtube-in-html-web-app-fails hope they fix this soon as well...